# Regex for currency symbol and amount html pattern

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm currently using the `pattern` attribute in an input field on my html form.

I have prefixed my form with a `£` symbol therefore I need the regex to match the symbol as well as `ONLY DIGITS` after.
The regex must not match the currency symbol on it's own but should match the currency symbol with any amount of digits after it.

I currently have `pattern="(\£\d+)"` however it seems like it does not work as it allows characters to be entered and also it matches the £ symbol on its own when it's supposed to match it with digits after only.

I used https://regexr.com/3gi1e which shows it is correct but doesn't work with `pattern`.

Comment: `(\£\d+)` Matches a pound sign plus 1+ digits. What exactly does you want to match and do you not want to match?

Comment: I want it to match a pound sign plus 1+ digits exactly like you said however it seems like it's not doing it as it is allowing characters to be entered.

Comment: You should not escape the pound sign, that is all you need to do - `pattern="£\d+"`. The `u` modifier that is used to compile the regex object from HTML5 pattern in Chrome and Firefox makes escaping rules more strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the HTML entity `&pound;` in your expression which seems to achieve what you're after:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="&pound;\d+" value="&pound;"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```